# Ambiguous column name in c# but not in SQL Server?

Tags: c#, sql-server, sqlexception

I am trying to execute a SQL command via c# but is telling me that I have an ambiguous column name. When I copy the query into SQL Server and execute it, it works fine. But through c#, it tells me

> Ambiguous column name 'SPCode'

This is my SQL string in c#:

```
string yourSQLstring = 
   "INSERT INTO totalTable (Catalogue, totalTable.SPCode, ProjNo, Quantity, Spare) " +
   "SELECT Catalogue, BOMtable.SPCode, ProjNo, SUM(Quantity) AS Quantity, (SELECT CEILING(CAST (.1 * SUM(Quantity) AS FLOAT))) AS Spare FROM MainSuperTable4 " +
   "FULL OUTER JOIN BOMtable ON PartNo = Catalogue " +
   "WHERE ProjNo= '" + SavingData.instance.projNumber + "' AND SPCode IS NOT NULL " +
   "GROUP BY Catalogue, ProjNo, SPCode";
```

This the code copied into SQL Server and edited to remove c# stuff:

```
INSERT INTO totalTable (Catalogue, SPCode, ProjNo, Quantity, Spare) 
   SELECT 
      Catalogue, SPCode, ProjNo, 
      SUM(Quantity) AS Quantity, 
      (SELECT CEILING(CAST (.1 * SUM(Quantity) AS FLOAT))) AS Spare 
   FROM MainSuperTable4 
   FULL OUTER JOIN BOMtable ON PartNo = Catalogue 
   WHERE 
       ProjNo = 'P140134' AND SPCode IS NOT NULL 
   GROUP BY 
       Catalogue, ProjNo, SPCode
```

Not sure why it would work in SQL Server and then not in C#?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: adding the structure of the three tables might be useful

Comment: You haven't *just* removed the "C# stuff", you've also removed the `totalTable.` within the column list for the insert. What happens if you re-introduce that?

Comment: why can't you add table names BOMtable .PartNo  = MainSuperTable4 .Catalogue

Comment: And, further, I'd also note that `BOMtable.` has also disappeared from the `SELECT` clause between the "c#" version and the plain SQL one. In short, it's difficult to tell why one works and the other doesn't because I highly doubt that what you're showing is the *actual* code, and/or you're not just copying the code between the two situations but also applying other edits.

Comment: In your `GROUP BY` statement, try using a fully qualified name for SPCode, like `BOMtable.SPCode`

Comment: and its not clear why you do a full join since you basicly force a inner join with your where clause

Comment: If you get in the habit of always using the alias.columnname notation you will avoid this problem. You will also enjoy the benefits of code that is easier to maintain because you don't have to guess which table a given column is coming from.

Answer (score 1):

Change your group by to this:

```
"GROUP BY Catalogue, ProjNo, BOMtable.SPCode";
```

Change your insert to this:

```
"INSERT INTO totalTable (Catalogue, SPCode, ProjNo, Quantity, Spare) " +
```